# mongodb map/reduce save plain results

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I wrote a finalize function doing

```
db.collection.save(value, {safe: 1});
```

in the end and not returning a value.
This worked fine until I upgraded to the current version.
Now MongoDB throws

```
invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: db has no properties nofile_b:16
```

I try to save my results plain, meaning value, value, value, ... instead of (key,value), (key,value), ... .

Is there a way to tell a map/reduce job to save just the values?
I don't want to run another command to collect move the values to a new collection.

thx

Answer (score 0):

If I may ask, which version of mongo were you using in which you were allowed to modify a separate collection in the finalize function?  This was not intended behavior.  I tried this with 1.8.3 and 2.0.2, and was not able to modify a separate collection.  I received the same error, "invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: db has no properties nofile_b:1"

The documents that are output by map reduce can only be in the form of {_id:"id", value:"value"}.  If you would like the output in a different format, you will have to do it programatically.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know which version exactly I used. I wrote the function about october 11. The project was on hold till now and worked by that time. When I upgraded last week, I encountered the problem.